# Seg fault while outputting 2-d array of strings

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, output, gnu

So i have been working on this code for a while, and I am not very skilled. I have created two classes one defines an item for a shopping list, and the other creates an array of the objects and outputs them as a list. The program works in my windows command prompt, but segfaults on GNU command line when I am outputting the array using cout statements.

```
void List::createList(Item ** itemPtr, int size)
{
    string** list1 = new string*[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        list1[i] = new string[5];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        list1[i][0] = itemPtr[i]->getName();
        list1[i][1] = itemPtr[i]->getUnit();
        list1[i][2] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRnumToBuy();
        list1[i][3] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRcost();
        list1[i][4] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRextCost();
    }
    cout << endl << left << fixed << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "Name";
    cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "Unit Type";
    cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "# of units";
    cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "Cost/Unit";
    cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "Total" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) <<setprecision(2)<<endl<< list1[i][0];
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << list1[i][1];
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << list1[i][2];
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << list1[i][3];
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << list1[i][4];
    }
}
```

Comment: `new`ing a standard container usually means you are doing something wrong. Why not use vectors of strings and avoid the headaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st loop should be :

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
  list1[i] = new string[5];
}
```

That is, loop till `size`, not till 5.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel like a bone head.

Answer (score 0):

```
string** list1 = new string*[size];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Looks like a bug to me: if `size` < 5 then you will be reading out of bounds of the array you have created.

```
list1[i][0] = itemPtr[i]->getName();
list1[i][1] = itemPtr[i]->getUnit();
list1[i][2] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRnumToBuy();
list1[i][3] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRcost();
list1[i][4] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRextCost();
```

This could fail if the size of the `itemPtr` array is less than `size`.

Another point, though not related to the crash you're seeing, you are leaking memory here. `list1` is a local variable that's not stored somewhere in your class. You are allocating memory for it on the heap, but do not free that memory (`delete`) it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I actually do have a line below the shared code to delete the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your using C++ not C so use the power of the vector

```
void List::createList(Item ** itemPtr, int size) {
    vector<vector<string>> list1;
    list1.resize(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        list1[i].resize(5);
        list1[i][0] = itemPtr[i]->getName();
        list1[i][1] = itemPtr[i]->getUnit();
        list1[i][2] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRnumToBuy();
        list1[i][3] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRcost();
        list1[i][4] = itemPtr[i]->getSTRextCost();
    }
    cout << endl << left << fixed << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "Name";
    cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "Unit Type";
    cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "# of units";
    cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "Cost/Unit";
    cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << "Total" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) <<setprecision(2)<<endl<< list1[i][0];
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << list1[i][1];
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << list1[i][2];
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << list1[i][3];
        cout << fixed << left << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << list1[i][4];
    }
}
```

Look Ma, no `new`s nor `delete`s.

Comment: Thanks Surt. I would have used vectors for this, however it was an assignment for a c++ class in which we were required to use arrays.